# implementing methods

Tags: java

I am comfused with the requirement "do not implement ADT(abstract data type). Implement push(), pop(), and isEmpty(). Can I implement those methods individually from an interface or create those methods locally inside the linkedStack class?

`

```
public class linkedStack<T>
{
  private int count;  
  private LinearNode<T> top;  
  private T [] stack;

  public void push (T data) {stack[top++] = data;}
  public T pop() {T result = stack[--top]; stack[top] = null;return result;}
  public boolean isEmpty() {return (top == 0);}

  public linkedStack()
  {count = 0;top = null;}

  public String toString ()
  {
    String result = "\n";

    String[][] grid = null;
    for (int row=0; row < grid.length; row++)
    {  for (int column=0; column < grid[row].length; column++)
        result += grid[row][column] + "";      
        result += "\n";
    }

    return result;
  }

  public class LinearNode<T>
  {
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;

    public LinearNode ()      {next = null;element = null;}
    public LinearNode (T elem){next = null;element = elem;}


  }  
}


`
```

Comment: Did they provide an interface? Also is a Java Convention to start your Class name with Upper case `public class LinkedStack<T>`

Answer (score 0):

An ADT is like a blueprint to build a Data Structure so I am assuming they don't want you to implement all the methods (i.e. implementing the ADT) but only the methods `pop()`, `push()` and `isEmpty()`